# What happens when itemprop="sameAs" is added to a link/image rather than just content?

Tags: html, schema

I wanted to add social profile links schema for SEO,
Now according to https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/social-profiles

```
<a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.facebook.com/your-company">FB</a>
```

It should work, but what if in my code it has to be:

```
<a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://twitter.com/your-company">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</a>
```

Would this be understood by Search Engines correctly as a twitter link or would they just understand it as a social media link without being able to figure out that the href points to twitter? I'm pretty sure it works, but I'd like to be more sure.